# Queries com várias associações em ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, query

Eu quero fazer em ruby on rails, isto:

```
SELECT * FROM isolateds 
  INNER JOIN genes ON geness.isolated_id = isolateds.id
  INNER JOIN stats ON stats.gene_id = genes.id
  INNER JOIN mutations ON stats.mutation_id = mutations.id
```

Quando eu faço:

`Isolated.joins(:genes).all`, o resultado é:

```
SELECT * FROM isolateds 
  INNER JOIN genes ON geness.isolated_id = isolateds.id
```

Mas quando faço, 
`Isolated.joins(:genes, :stats).all`, dá-me logo erro e nem consigo chegar à tabela mutations, o que estou a fazer mal?

Answer (score 0):

Já consegui basta apenas fazer:

```
Isolated.joins(:drugs, genes: :mutations ).all
```

Agora o meu problema e não me mostrar tudo de todas as tabelas, ele está com apenas duas colunas, alguém me consegue explicar porque?
Eu gostaria, mesmo que para um certo isolado, se não houvesse nenhum gene que aparece-se na mesma.

Answer (score 0):

A solução para essa situação no Rails 3, seria:

```
Isolated.joins(:genes => :stats => :mutations).all
```

Isso resolveria o primeiro problema que você apresentou.
Sobre a pergunta na sua resposta, no Rails você está trabalhando com ActiveRecord como uma camada de gerenciamento ao acesso no Banco de Dados, portanto, seria necessário ver nos seus modelos como estão os relacionamentos para que se pudesse precisar se seria o caso de utilizar um left_outer_join ou se o proprio objeto após carregado em uma variavel já não traria essa informação para você.